# Asp.net core 3.1 redirect empty route to default language route

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application, .net-core-3.1

I am using multi-language angular app in my project as follows:

```
app.Map("/en", en =>
{
    en.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer(LocalSpaServerUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp/dist/ClientApp/en")),
            };
        }
    });
});

app.Map("/bg", bg =>
{
    bg.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp/dist/ClientApp/bg")),
        };
    });
});
```

I want the default route to be the /en one: when a user attempts to acces '/' I want it to redirect to '/en'.
Keep in mind this is outside of Angular's router, so I cannot handle this there.

Comment: Making kode for "/en" reusable and and app.Map("/" ... ?

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work. It seems the path should match the serve directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a lot, I found the correct way:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.Value == "/")
    {
        // rewrite and continue processing
        context.Request.Path = "/en/";
    }

    await next();
});
```